# Make jCarousel slider slide continously

Tags: javascript, jquery, jcarousel

I have a jCarousel, with autoscrolling, like: http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/examples/static_auto.html

Is it possible to make it slide continously, smoothly? instead of scrolling few items at a time?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function mycarousel_initCallback(carousel) {
    carousel.buttonNext.bind('click', function() { carousel.startAuto(0); });
    carousel.buttonPrev.bind('click', function() { carousel.startAuto(0); });
    carousel.clip.hover(function() { carousel.stopAuto(); }, function() { carousel.startAuto(); }); };
    jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
        jQuery('#mycarousel').jcarousel({ auto: 1, wrap: 'circular', animation: 'fast', scroll: 1, initCallback: mycarousel_initCallback });
});       
</script>

<ul id="mycarousel" class="jcarousel-skin-tango">
<!-- My slides here -->
</ul>
```

Also, can I do something to keep the autoscroll after I click on the navigation arrows, and the mouse is not hover the slider?

I haven't found nothing related in their documentation: http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found what I was looking for. So my code look like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function mycarousel_initCallback(carousel) {
    carousel.buttonNext.bind('click', function() { carousel.startAuto(); });
    carousel.buttonPrev.bind('click', function() { carousel.startAuto(); });
    carousel.clip.hover(function() { carousel.stopAuto(); }, function() { carousel.startAuto(); }); };
    jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
        jQuery('#mycarousel').jcarousel({ auto: .01, wrap: 'circular', animation: 2000, scroll: 1, easing: 'linear', initCallback: mycarousel_initCallback  });
});       
</script>
```

It looks like these two settings combined "animation: 2000, easing: 'linear'" , are doing what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Delete that line so your hover mouse will not stop animation:

```
    carousel.clip.hover(function() { carousel.stopAuto(); }, function() {       carousel.startAuto(); }); };
```

and try delete this:

```
    carousel.buttonNext.bind('click', function() { carousel.startAuto(0); });
    carousel.buttonPrev.bind('click', function() { carousel.startAuto(0); });
```

it may help you to get not starting all the time from (0) element. but first please check it.
so as you see you can delete whole function callback.

Comment: Thanks, you pointed me in the right direction regarding my second issue. To keep them slide continously after I click on navigation arrows I have remove "0" from carousel.startAuto(0);

Comment: Glad to help with my js laguage)